# WARNING: fake for private method found; such fakes will no longer be supported

Tags: java, jmockit

I got this warning in JMockit 1.46.

I use `MockUp<>` and `@Mock`

I believe JMockit hope to use other way to mock private method.

Cloud you help to shield this warning or find a better way to mock private method?